# How to emulate key presses in vim script

Tags: vim, netrw

my question is similar to this one https://superuser.com/questions/277051/how-can-i-emulate-key-presses-on-vim-startup

I'm using the plugin netrw in my vim instead of nerdtree in that question. I add the following line to enable netrw automatically.

```
autocmd BufWinEnter * :Ve
```

While open vim, I need to press ^W^W each time because the active buffer is the left one, where the netrw is located.

How can I make vim emulate these key presses on startup? In fact, I've got it works before, but I didn't save my .vimrc in a recently re-installation of OS.

The answer of that question doesn't work for me.

My environment:
Mac OS X 10.9.5
MacVim Snapshot 73

Any answers appreciated, thanks a lot :)

Comment: Can you please state more clearly how the mentioned question didn't work for you?

Comment: did you try adding `:execute "normal \<C-W>\<C-W>"` to the end of your `.vimrc`?

Answer (score 1):

Best way is by just appending the command to the existing `:autocmd` (separated by `|`):

```
autocmd BufWinEnter * Vexplore | wincmd w
```

#### Notes

- By using `BufWinEnter`, this will open a netrw split on *each* displaying of a buffer. If you just want to trigger this once at Vim startup, `VimEnter` is the right event to use.
- Don't abbreviate commands inside plugins and configuration; this is just to save keys on interactive use. It's easier to understand this way, and you don't have the risk of having to adapt all instances when you install / define another command with the same initial letters (e.g. `:VerticalSplit`). Also, you don't need the `:` in autocmds.
- For `<C-W>` window commands, there's the special `:wincmd` Ex command to trigger those. For all else, you would use `:execute 'normal! \<C-w>\<C-w>'`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I know the difference between BufWinEnter and VimEnter, BufWinEnter is what I want.
I've tried  autocmd BufWinEnter * Vexplore | wincmd w  and even :execute 'normal! \<C-w>\<C-w>' but all doesn't work....

Comment: Does it work when you type it: `:Vexplore | wincmd w` (it does for me)? Do you have other autocmds?